# How to set the language for the user while it is created?

Tags: users, 7, i18n-l10n

How to set the language for a user while it is created from `admin/people/create`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 7 doesn't need third-party modules to have a language selector for user profiles.

- Enable the Local module.
- Enable one or more languages in /admin/config/regional/language; the settings page initially shows only English, generally. It would show another language if Drupal has been installed using a different language.
- When you now edit a user profile, you can set the language associated with the user by choosing between the languages you enabled.

Comment: True. I was thinking in my case because I am using it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it was a simple thing, just that I didn't enabled the language. So the steps are:

- install and activate [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module
- go to `admin/config/regional/language` and add the languages you want
- then in `admin/people/create` you will have a language selector.