# Default language for role

Tags: users, i18n-l10n

I'm building a website in French as default and only front language but I have to figure out how to do this:

I have administrator and manager roles, both are ok using the french language for both front UI and Admin panels but I also have a role "normal-users" for wich I want to set the default front UI and Admin panels to english by default at registration. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in this topic below

[How to set the language for the user while it is created?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1384/how-to-set-the-language-for-the-user-while-it-is-created)

Just read it quickly, this seems  to be what you need?

Comment: I already set that to English but it doen's change ! Also, it says that the laguage applies to e-mails not the UI.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.